# Spring WebService - Unable to call service that requires proxy with username and password

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, proxy

I am trying to use the Spring WebServiceTemplate in my Java code to call a proteceted webservice offered by a vendor

here is the spring config for my webserviceTemplate

```
    <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
        <property name="messageSender">
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
                 <property name="httpClient" ref="httpClient"/> 
                <property name="credentials" ref="credentials" />
            </bean>
        </property> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="credentials" class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
            <constructor-arg value="${wsdl.username}:${wsdl.password}"/> 
<!--            <constructor-arg index="0" value="${wsdl.username}"/>
            <constructor-arg index="1" value="${wsdl.password}"/> -->
     </bean>

    <bean id="proxy" class="org.apache.http.HttpHost">
        <constructor-arg value="${http.proxy.host}" />
        <constructor-arg value="${http.proxy.port}" />
    </bean> 


<!-- See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340470/how-to-spring-ioc-and-httpclient-4-3-1-closeablehttpclient
for configuring the HttpRequestBuilder in spring -->
<bean id="requestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig" factory-method="custom">
<property name="proxy" ref="proxy" /> 
    <property name="socketTimeout" value="50000" /> 
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="50000" />  
</bean>

<bean id="requestConfig" factory-bean="requestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" factory-method="create">
    <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="requestConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClient" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />
```

I need to use a proxy to get through to the service. Also the webserivces requires a username and password.
I have verified numerous times that the proxy and credential details are valid

The code is use to call this webservice is

```
public boolean getItems() {

    StringBuilder soapMessage = FileUtil.readFileContent(BASE_CONFIG_LOCATION + GET_ITEMS_XML_TEMPLTE);
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(soapMessage.toString()));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    String endpoint = baseURL + FIND_SERVICE_ENDPOINT;

    boolean webserviceResult = webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(endpoint,source, result);


    return webserviceResult;
}
```

When  I call this code - I get the following exception

```
 org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceIOException: I/O error: null; nested exception is org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:543)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:492)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:436)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:421)
    at com.test.api.WebServiceImpl.getChecklist(WebServiceImpl.java:69)
    at com.test.api.WebServiceRealCallsTest.testGetChecklist_Success(WebServiceRealCallsTest.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsConnection.onSendAfterWrite(HttpComponentsConnection.java:119)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.send(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:47)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendRequest(WebServiceTemplate.java:622)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:585)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present
    at org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(RequestContent.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:182)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    ... 43 more
```

Can anyone offer any guidance on what I need to do to get this service up and running? Perhaps my configuration is not correct?

Thank you

################ UPDATE

If I use the following code - my webservice call returns successfully
However I would rather do all of this in spring and also the httpClient getParams method is deprecated

```
    public boolean getItems() {

    HttpComponentsMessageSender sender = (HttpComponentsMessageSender) webServiceTemplate.getMessageSenders()[0];
         sender.getHttpClient().getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,
                                    proxy); 

    StringBuilder soapMessage = FileUtil.readFileContent(BASE_CONFIG_LOCATION + GET_ITEMS_XML_TEMPLTE);
    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(soapMessage.toString()));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

    String endpoint = baseURL + FIND_SERVICE_ENDPOINT;

    boolean webserviceResult = webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(endpoint,source, result);

    return webserviceResult;
}
```

#### Update 1pm GMT

I noticed that if I specify the httpClient in the xml for the message sender that the class org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient is used

If I dont specify the httpClient - the class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient is used

Also in another interesting point, in the class org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender

```
/**
 * Create a new instance of the {@code HttpClientMessageSender} with a default {@link HttpClient} that uses a
 * default {@link org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager}.
 */
public HttpComponentsMessageSender() {
    org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient defaultClient =
            new org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient(new org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager());
    defaultClient.addRequestInterceptor(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor(), 0);

    this.httpClient = defaultClient;
    setConnectionTimeout(DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
    setReadTimeout(DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);
}

/**
 * Create a new instance of the {@code HttpClientMessageSender} with the given
 * {@link HttpClient} instance.
 * <p>
 * This constructor does not change the given {@code HttpClient} in any way. As such,
 * it does not set timeouts, nor does it
 * {@linkplain org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient#addRequestInterceptor(org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor) add}
 * the {@link RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor}.
 *
 * @param httpClient the HttpClient instance to use for this sender
 */
public HttpComponentsMessageSender(HttpClient httpClient) {
    Assert.notNull(httpClient, "httpClient must not be null");
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

As you can see - for the DefaultClient - it calls a method to remove soapHeaders but not for the HttpClient. I looked at this method and thought about adding an intercepotor for doing the same job but the HttpRequest is not available on any of the interceptor methods

Any thoughts on where I can proceed from here?

Comment: I think it is related to authorization header. Please checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494148/org-apache-http-client-clientprotocolexception

Comment: right ok thats a good suggestion. I am trying to run my requests through the eclipse TCP/IP interceptor but with no joy as the endpoint is https

Comment: what about checking directly on the browser?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this.  The trick is to add the interceptor to the custom client.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new NoopHostnameVerifier())
    .setSSLContext(ContextUtil.getTrustAllCertsContext())
    .addInterceptorFirst(new HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())
    .build();
```